# create dynamic reports using core php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, report

Currently we are doing a project to manage projects and our client need a dynamic reports which he can get Time Sheet Project wise.

Let me explain the situation.

3 database tables.

Project table, user table and task table.

This is the sample reports format with a sample data, but structure is the same.

[image: Sample report structure]

Multiple users can work on a single project and user can work on multiple projects at the same time.

This is what i have tried to up to now.

```
<?php

/////get projects which are not finished/////
$sql_project = "SELECT * FROM project where P_Status!='finished'";
$result_project = mysql_query($sql_project) or die("Error in query: $sql_project.".mysql_error());

////////get users from the users table
$sql_getUsers="select * from tbl_user where status='Active' order by U_Name";
$result_getUsers=mysql_query($sql_getUsers);

    ?>
 <tr>
    <td>Project</td>
    <td>Client</td>
    <td>Estimated Cost</td>
    <td >Total spent to date </td>
    <?php
    while($row_getUsers=mysql_fetch_array($result_getUsers))
    {
    ?>
    <td ><?php echo $row_getUsers['U_Name']; ?></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

</tr>
<?php

while($row_project=mysql_fetch_array($result_project))
{
$individualProject=trim($row_project['P_Title']);

$sql_tasks = "Select SUM(Time)as totalTime from tbl_txn where project like '%$individualProject%' and Date<='$endDate'";
$result_sql = mysql_query($sql_tasks) or die("Error in query: $sql_file_no.".mysql_error());


  ?>
<?php
while($row_sql_tasks=mysql_fetch_array($result_sql))
{

?>


<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_project['P_Title']; ?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $row_project['P_Client']; ?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $row_project['estimatedCost']; ?></td>
    <td ><?php echo round($row_sql_tasks['totalTime']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo round($row_getIndiUserTime['Time']); ?></td>
 <?php


    }
}
    ?>
```

I have managed to display the users, but i have no idea how to display users have work on each project?.
on project A, how much time User 1 has spent and user 2 like wise.
hope i have clearly mentioned about the problem.
can anyone help me on this please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The idea to do this is to join a table in mysql.
[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is a resource you can learn how to use mysql join table and show the data accordingly. Hope this will help you.